# Usage of hasMany through tables

Tags: mysql, database

I have users table and then their interests table.

Is it best to have hasMany through table to manage the relationship between two or would I be better off to do a CSV into one of the columns in Users table.

I've been using hasMany through tables so far but was wondering what the best options are.

I appreciate any experienced advice on this database management issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly: one of your choices is to save comma separated values in a column of a relational database?

This is almost -never- a valid option. Don't do that. Only in some EXTREME cases where you have some sort of data-warehouse of... no, what am I thinking. Don't ever save relations as a comma separated list in a column.

Comment: Thanks for this advice. Then do you think I should always use pivot (hasMany through) table? Is there any better ways of managing this relationship?

Comment: A user can have multiple interests, and multiple users have the same interest I presume: that means you should have 3 tabels: `users`, `interest` and `userIntersts`.